# Cannot colour specific rows in DataGridView

Tags: powershell, datagridview, colors, icons

I am running a PowerShell form pulling info from an array and displaying in a DataGridView.  I would like to be able to highlight/colour a specific row based the text in a specific field.  I'm pretty close, but I cannot figure out how to target the specific row to be highlighted.  Currently the whole grid gets highlighted.  Ultimately, I would like to have a nice icon on the left in a new field to indicate the row, but highlighting for now will do the trick.

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,440)
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)


$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 4
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Name"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "ID"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "Description"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Memory"
$dataGridView.Columns[0].width = 240

get-process | foreach {
$dataGridView.Rows.Add($_.Name,$_.ID,$_.Description,$_.WorkingSet) | out-null
}

foreach ($Row in $dataGridView.Rows) {
Write-Host $Row.Index $Row.Value
}

foreach ($Row in $dataGridView.Rows) {
   if ($Row.Name -eq 'chrome') {
       $row.defaultcellstyle.backcolor = "Yellow"
   } else {
       $row.defaultcellstyle.backcolor = "Red"
   }
}

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `$row` does not have a `name` property. You can confirm this by doing `$row | Get-Member`. Therefore your `$Row.Name` would always be null and the condition would evaluate to `$false` hence the wall of red you are seeing.

```
foreach ($Row in $dataGridView.Rows) {
   if ($Row.Cells[0].Value -eq 'chrome') {
       $row.defaultcellstyle.backcolor = "Yellow"
   } else {
       $row.defaultcellstyle.backcolor = "Red"
   }
}
```

Since you have the first cell as your name column we look at the value of the first cell in every row for comparison now. Still looking to see if there is a better way as assuming the first position, even though correct in the case, does not seem like the best approach. Still, it highlights properly now.

I don't know if this was a typo but you were doing an arithmetic comparison on a string as well. So assuming we did not have that other issue `$Row.Name - 'chrome'` should have been `$Row.Name -eq 'chrome'`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that is perfect.  Yes, I spotted my typo, I was coming back to fix it when I saw your answer :) .